# Passing argument to sub-functions in C

Tags: c

A simple problem, but somehow I can't find the solution,

I want to pass basically, in my program one of my arguments is the desired file to send the program output to.

It's not really an issue to set it up in main() however, I'm wondering how can I process argv[] in functions that are not main.

I tried it like this:

```
    void print_ip(struct arp* arp, char* argv[]){
       char *myfile = argv[2];
       if ( strlen(argv[2]) <= 0 ){
        printf("ERROR: Please specify a proper interface \n");
       }
       else {
        strcpy(myfile, argv[2]);
       }

       f = fopen(myfile, "w");
       if (f != NULL){
         printf("Found an IP address \n");
         fprintf(f, "\t<ipv4>%s, %s</ipv4>", arp->ipv4_destination, arp->ipv4_source);
       }
       else {
        printf("ERROR: Failed to open file \n");
        exit(1);
       }
    }
```

This function works, only issue is when I try to launch the function from elsewhere

for example

```
   void arp_scan(struct arp*, int bsd_socket){
     ... code ...
     print_ip(&arp, argv);
   }
```

i get the following error:

> scanner.c: In function ‘arp_scan’: scanner.c:187:25: error: ‘argv’
>   undeclared (first use in this function)
>        print_ip(&arp, argv);

Surely there must be a way other than declaeing char *argv[] in every single function to be able to proccess it from one to another

Comment: There are these things called function arguments (or parameters). You can use them to pass around the `argv` from `main`, just as you pass around other values.

Comment: i don't know if im missing something today, but I still don't understand how can I pass the argv[] argument to a different function when argv[] is specific to main so it's a function variable instead of a global one.

Also no need to act so arrogant, we're all human after-all and we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only main can accept arguments from the command line (argv). if you want to pass these command line args to a function then you need to pass them as a paramater.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int passingvars(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < argc)
    {
        printf(argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    passingvars(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I was trying to avoid - hence my question, since I have like 6 interconnected functions all reliant on that argument because of their prints. 

Either way, I guess it's just a bit of busy work and will work afterwards.

Thanks :)

Comment: Or you could put them in a global variable, but that makes your program less flexible.